# How to re-arrange position of this menu items

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i have array and i want to rearrange some element of that array like i want 2nd element should be in 0th position and 3rd element should be in 2nd position. look screenshot for reference and final result should be like this -> Quicky Starts | Guilds | Reference Docs | Help

and if i add any new item to array then it should appear at last position

[image]

```
<Nav className="me-auto">
          {newNavArr.map((button, index) => (
            <NavLink
              key={index}
              to={button.slug}
              position="relative"
              padding="20px"
            >
              {button.title}
            </NavLink>
          ))}
        </Nav>
```

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Are there any constraints related to time or space complexity or if its the requirement of your application simply create a new array with strings you want in place and replace it. const array = [' ','','','']

Comment: how can you do this? post updated please look this..

Comment: const newnavArr = [{ title: " Quicky Starts"}, {title: " Guides}...]

Answer (score 1):

Is far way more optimal to make this position-ordering with CSS applying a flexbox (`display: flex`) + `order` rule. It's worth noting that the other solutions suggested rely on different mapping methods (such as `splice`, `includes`, and `forEach`) that create a new instance of the array (which is later cleaned up by the garbage collector but it's not optimal at all)

```
<Nav className="me-auto">
  {newNavArr.map((button, index) => (
    <NavLink
      key={index}
      to={button.slug}
      position="relative"
      padding="20px"
    >
      {button.title}
    </NavLink>
  ))}
</Nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
.me-auto{
  display: flex;
}

.me-auto:nth-child(3){
   order: 2;
}

.me-auto:nth-child(2){
   order: 3;
}
```

You can add your custom order as desired to the rest of the elements

Comment: your solution work perfectly as i want but when i add new item to array it array in 3rd position but i want that newly added element should go in last.. every newly added element go in last

Comment: You can add a negative `order` numbers as well. Try it playing around with `flex-wrap: wrap` in the parent container. In that case what I'd do is to give a negative order to the elements and sort them as desired and when a new element is added, since it won't have an order, will be placed in the end by default (even a `flex-direction: row-reverse` + negative numbers will work)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this, first you need to create a list of sorted arrays, if your data is coming dynamically then you can sort the data in a new array according to your array as you can see below code, I hope this would be helpful.

```js
const arr = ["Guilds", "Reference Docs", "Help", "Quicky Starts"]

const sortedArr = ["Quicky Starts", "Guilds", "Ahmad", "Reference Docs", "Help"]

let newArr = []

arr.forEach(element => {
  if (sortedArr.includes(element)) {
    const findIndex = sortedArr.findIndex(i => i === element);
    newArr[findIndex] = element;
  }
})

let result = newArr.filter(d => d !== undefined)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the algorithm to change any position of an array write the element name you want to change and write second element name you want to swap with.
Code:

```
function change(arr, from, to){


arr.splice(arr.indexOf(to), 0, arr.splice(arr.indexOf(from),1)[0])
}
let arr = ["Quicky Starts","Guilds","Reference Docs","Help"];
console.log(arr) // return ["Quicky Starts", "Guilds", "Reference Docs", "Help"]

change(arr, "Guilds", "Quicky Starts");

console.log(arr) // return  ["Guilds", "Quicky Starts", "Reference Docs", "Help"]
```

If you want to change the 2nd element should be the 1st position do this again.

```
change(arr, "Reference Docs", "Quicky Starts");
console.log(arr) // return ["Guilds", "Reference Docs", "Quicky Starts", "Help"]
```